# React useState in context does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-state-management

I'm using React to create a login page which after logging in should keep track if the user is logged in. I figured using the react context and state hook would be easier than using something as big and complex as Redux.

I created a login function which works, and after a successfull login it should update my state in my context. The login works (i get a status 200) but my state is not updated in my context.

My 'AuthContext.jsx' looks like this

```js
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { login, register } from "../API/apiMethods";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const authSetter = (state) => {
    setAuthenticated(state);
  };

  const authGetter = () => {
    return authenticated;
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        authSetter,
        authGetter,
        login,
        register,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My login function looks like this

```js
/**
 * @description Handles login
 * @param {String} email
 * @param {String} password
 * @returns {Boolean}
 */
export const login = async(email, password) => {
  try {
    let authenticated = false;
    await fetch(BASE_URL + "login", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      }),
    }).then((res) => {
      authenticated = res.status === 200 ? true : false;
    });
    return authenticated;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
};
```

And in my login form i try to update the authentication boolean after a successfull login

```js
const {
  login,
  authSetter,
  authGetter
} = useContext(AuthContext);
const submit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  await login(email, password)
    .then((authSuccess) => {
      if (authSuccess) {
        console.log("login successfull");
        authSetter(true);
      }
    })
    .then(() => console.log(authGetter()));
};
```

With this code i expected the console output to be a printed string with 'login successfull' and a printed boolean true.
But it seems my state was not updated even though i did call the setter.

[image: my console output]

I don't know why it won't update, can anyone help me?

Comment: `setAuthenticated` is an asynchronous function i.e. it is not updated immediately,that is why you are getting false in log. Try logging the value outside the `submit` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code does exactly what it is supposed to. When you update the state it does not happen immediately.

```
const submit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  await login(email, password)
    .then((authSuccess) => {
      if (authSuccess) {
        console.log("login successfull");
        authSetter(true);
      }
    })
    .then(() => console.log(authGetter()));
};
```

When you call the `authSetter(true);`, the state update is queued and once the then callback completes it goes to the next `then` in the chain which has your `authGetter()`. Now the state update does not happen immediately as I explained, it is queued. So when the last `then` callback is executed the state update which is queued has not happened and you still see `false` which is the old value.

You can refactor your `AuthProvider` in the following way, there is no need to wrap the setter in a function as it would create a new instance of the function when the state is updated (`useState` on the other hand returns a memoized value of the setter function) and you can simply return the `authenticated` state without the getter which again has the same issue.

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { login, register } from "../API/apiMethods";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        setAuthenticated,
        authenticated,
        login,
        register,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In your form, you can have an extra `useEffect` to check whether you have logged in successfully. the `useEffect` will run when the `authenticated` state has been updated.

```
const {
  login,
  setAuthenticated,
  authenticated
} = useContext(AuthContext);

const submit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const authSuccess = await login(email, password);
  if (authSuccess) {
     console.log("login successfull");
     authSetter(true);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(authenticated);
}, [authenticated]);
```